# Can <canvas> be used to make web application for mobile browsers?

Tags: iphone, android, html, canvas

I'm interested in whether  can be used to create a painting and uploading application that will function on the iPhone, Android, and BlackBerry. The point being to have a Flash, cool version on a website visible on a PC, and a simpler non-Flash version on mobile browsers.

This would be my first web app on a mobile browser, so I've no clue about this. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely. And since Flash is disallowed on iOS, it is the only real solution for that one.

Canvas works on OS 6 (BlackBerry Torch, but NOT Blackberry Storm/2).

Canvas works on iOS and Android.

Not all canvas functions work, though, but they are mostly small problems. Some gradients on text, for instance, won't show up on Android last I looked.

Answer (score 1):

As long as those devices support Canvas2D and javascript, web applications that are run on these devices can use canvas for graphics and graphic interaction; with the controls generally kept off the canvas, because xhtml+css already offers low cost (in terms of cpu and memory) solutions for UI elements.